# how to get url from outlook addin mailitem body html

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

first of all, How to get the html message body,
then in the body i need to fetch the URL links, its hyper link, text and the domain name of the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Mailitem.HTMLBody has the HTML markup for the email item, so to get access to it:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
//---
Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailitem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApplication.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
string myhtml = mailitem.HTMLBody;
```

Then you need to parse out the links.  Assuming they are actually coded as  anchor tags, you could use a regex like the below as a starting point:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myhtml, @"<a\shref=""(?<url>.*?)"">(?<text>.*?)</a>");
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("URL: " + m.Groups["url"].Value + " -- Text = " + m.Groups["text"].Value);
}
```

The above is regex is from this [MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/353a7c05-212e-45a0-84c4-8fc0ab8fac2a/regex-to-pull-out-all-html-anchor-tags-href-plus-the-link-text)

Finally, to get the domain name, you can either modify the regex above, or create a [URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the work for you.

Comment: Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mail != null)
            {
                mail.body
                            
               
            },Is there a way to check for url in the mail.body item of the OutlookMailItem object mail.